# How do I search through an ArrayList for the lowest number and shortest duration?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, foreach, max

I have 3 classes. I'm learning about interfaces and the interface class TravelCost must have public abstract and the method type and name so that it is consistent through all three classes. The three classes (AirTravelCost, TrainTravelCost, CarTravelCost) will implement TravelCost. I have all that set and tested to work. However, the test page which I assume is where you input a search through the arrayList for the lowest cost and shortest duration. I don't know how to do this as I've never done this before in an ArrayList. Here the sample code in the test class:

```
import java.util.*;

 public class TestTravelCost
 {
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    /*Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object

    System.out.println("Number of Miles: ");
    double numOfMiles = scn.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Hotel cost per night: ");
    double cost = scn.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Description: ");
    String description = scn.nextLine();*/

    TravelCost c = new CarTravelCost(400, 200, "Boston");//instantiate object for car travel
    TravelCost t = new TrainTravelCost(6, 60.0, "Boston"); //instantiate object for train travel
    TravelCost a = new AirTravelCost(224, "20110103", "0743" , "20110103", "1153", "Boston");//instantiate object for air travel

    ArrayList<TravelCost> AL = new ArrayList<TravelCost>();//array list for car travel
    AL.add(c);
    AL.add(t);
    AL.add(a);

    for(TravelCost tc : AL)
    {
        System.out.println(tc.toString());
    }
   }
}
```

Output:
Car travel to Boston will take 7.2727272727272725 hours and cost 210.0 
Train travel to Boston will take 6.0 hours and cost 70.0 
Air travel to Boston will take 1.0166666666666666 and cost 243.48888888888888 //this is not the correct calculation, I don't know where I'm wrong but its suppose to be the same as the shortest duration.I guess I'm not good at math.

Here's the calculation method I used for Air Travel

```
    public double getDuration()
{
    //---DEPARTURE---//
    int Dyear = Integer.parseInt(departureDate.substring(0,3)); //2011
    int Dmonth = Integer.parseInt(departureDate.substring(4,5));//01
    int Dday = Integer.parseInt(departureDate.substring(6,7));//03

    int Dhour = Integer.parseInt(departureTime.substring(0,1));//0743
    int Dminute = Integer.parseInt(departureTime.substring(2,3));//1153
    //---ARRIVAL---//
    int Ayear = Integer.parseInt(arrivalDate.substring(0,3)); //2011
    int Amonth = Integer.parseInt(arrivalDate.substring(4,5));//01
    int Aday = Integer.parseInt(arrivalDate.substring(6,7));//03

    int Ahour = Integer.parseInt(arrivalTime.substring(0,1));//0743
    int Aminute = Integer.parseInt(arrivalTime.substring(2,3));//1153

    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(Dyear, Dmonth, Dday, Dhour, Dminute);//departure date & time
    GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar(Ayear, Amonth, Aday, Ahour, Aminute);//arrival date & time

    //date = arrivalDate - departureDate;//2011-01-03 - 2011-01-03 = 0
    //time = arrivalTime - departureTime;//0734 - 1153 = 410

    double duration = (Math.abs(date.getTimeInMillis() - time.getTimeInMillis()) / 60000.0) / 60.0;
    return duration;
  `enter code here` }
```

How do I get this result in my code?

LOWEST COST: Train Travel to Boston will take 11.0 hours and cost 70.0 
SHORTEST DURATION: Air Travel to Boston will take 4.166666666666667 hours cost 234.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the `TravelCost` interface, but to achieve what you want it should at least have a getDuration and getCost method.

```
public interface TravelCost {
    ... // what you already have in the interface definition
    public double getDuration();
    public double getCost();
}
```

Armed with that, I'd create a small dummy class implementing the basics to be comparable on these properties:

```
public DummyTC implements TravelCost {
    private double cost;
    private double duration;

    public DummyTC(double cost, double duration) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    // and other methods/properties imposed by TravelCost
}
```

This will allow you to find what you're looking for:

```
// instantiate 2 DummyTC's with impossibly high cost &durations

TravelCost cheapest = new DummyTC(99999999999.99, 99999999999.99);
TravelCost shortest = new DummyTC(99999999999.99, 99999999999.99);

// iterate over the List

for(TravelCost tc : AL) {
    // if present tc is cheaper than cheapest, swap
    if ( tc.getCost() < cheapest.getCost() ) {
        cheapest = tc;
    }
    // if present tc is shorter than shortest, swap
    if ( tc.getDuration() < shortest.getDuration() ) {
        shortest = tc;
    }
}

// at this point cheapest and shortest will contain the cheapest and shortest 
// ways of transportation, so we print them out.

System.out.println(cheapest.toString());
System.out.println(shortest.toString());
```

Another thing, your date handling code is horribly convoluted.  Have a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Date date = null;
Date time = null;
// create a SimpleDateFormat instance for your time/date format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
try {
    // parse it
    date = format.parse(departureDate);
    // done
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // departureDate could not be parsed, you should handle that case here
}

try {
    // parse it
    time = format.parse(arrivalTime);
    // done
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // arrivalTime could not be parsed, you should handle that case here
}
```

As Date also has a [routine to get the epoch-millis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) you can continue with the code you already have, although a `long` is probably a better return-type than a double in this case.